# Travis CI adds "index" before handler_name during deployment to AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, travis-ci

I'm using Travis-ci to deploy lambda function. I've created `.travis.yml` file according to [Lambda deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/lambda/), see file content below.

```
language: generic
deploy:
  provider: lambda
  function_name: MyFunction
  region: us-east-1
  role: correct_roleid
  runtime: python3.6
  handler_name: lambda/testfile.lambda_handler
  access_key_id: key_id
  secret_access_key:
    secure: secret
```

The folder structure of my project:

```
|   .editorconfig
|   .gitignore
|   .travis.yml
\---lambda
        testfile.py
```

After the deployment, in `Handler` field I have `index.lambda/testfile.lambda_handler` value.

**My question:**

How to say to Travis-ci use exact value, which I've set in `.travis.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handler_name` needs to be the function name. You should also set `module_name` (see [docs](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl#lambda)).

> **module_name**: Optional. The name of the module that exports the handler. Defaults to `index`.

So try something like:

```
module_name: lambda/testfile
handler_name: lambda_handler
```

If that doesn't work, try creating `__init__.py` in `lambda` folder. And if that doesn't work, try moving `lambda_handler.py` to the root folder. You can make it import files from your folder to keep an organized file structure.

Comment: kichik, thx, I slightly modified your code and it worked. I've changed module name to  `module_name: lambda/testfile`.