# Travis-CI Deployment issue for AWS Lambda and Java

Tags: travis-ci

When deploying code to lambdas for a java project there was an issue at first with `index.` being added to my handler path. Using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620548/2612651 I was able to get by that problem.

Now the issue is in Java it is using `module_name.handler_name` but instead of `.` it should be `::`.

Side note is there a concise list of all the .travis.yml commands anywhere? I cannot seem to find it.

Here is the deploy section of my .travis.yml file it puts the two artifact where I want I believe.

```
deploy:
  - provider: lambda
    access_key_id: $AWS_KEY
    secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET
    function_name: "grant-jwt"
    region: "us-east-2"
    role: "<arn>"
    runtime: "java8"
    module_name: "com.dapper.cloud.function.GrantJwt"
    handler_name: "handleRequest"
    file: "./grant-jwt/target/grant-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

- provider: lambda
    access_key_id: $AWS_KEY
    secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET
    function_name: "verify-jwt"
    region: "us-east-2"
    role: "<arn>"
    runtime: "java8"
    module_name: "com.dapper.cloud.function.VerifyJwt"
    handler_name: "handleRequest"
    file: "./verify-jwt/target/verify-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I actually ran into this issue too, and when i found the answer i felt silly. The correct way to to this would be to have the `module_name` be the package path and the `handler_name` name be `Class::handlerFunc`. Also `file` is not supported, looking at the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment-v2/providers/lambda/) the parameter you want is `zip`.

so for your case it would be

```
deploy:
  - provider: lambda
    access_key_id: $AWS_KEY
    secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET
    function_name: "grant-jwt"
    region: "us-east-2"
    role: "<arn>"
    runtime: "java8"
    module_name: "com.dapper.cloud.function"
    handler_name: "GrantJwt::handleRequest"
    zip: "./grant-jwt/target/grant-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

- provider: lambda
    access_key_id: $AWS_KEY
    secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET
    function_name: "verify-jwt"
    region: "us-east-2"
    role: "<arn>"
    runtime: "java8"
    module_name: "com.dapper.cloud.function"
    handler_name: "VerifyJwt::handleRequest"
    zip: "./verify-jwt/target/verify-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing a pull request for travis-ci. The logic for naming the handler was not very intelligent based on runtime. My change took that into account.  Likewise, some of the default settings for timeout and ram was very low. Fulls details here https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/pull/1018. That was updated as well. I moved over to GitHub Actions so probably won't be able to verify this fix.